# How to control ripple last color during long press

Tags: android

Currently, I have a selector on a view. When I long press on the view, it will transits from normal color to pure red color.

### linear_layout_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_drawable" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_drawable" />
</selector>
```

It looks as following, when I long press on it.

[image]

The behavior during long press is

```
normal color -> pure red color (Happens immediately)
```

---

Now, I would like to have a ripple effect on it. So, what I'm doing is

### drawable-v21/linear_layout_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ff0000">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/linear_layout_selector_for_ripple"/>
</ripple>
```

### drawable-v21/linear_layout_selector_for_ripple.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- It is important to remove state_pressed so that ripple can kicked in -->
    <!-- <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_drawable" /> -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_drawable" />
</selector>
```

When I long press on it, I can see the ripple effect.

[image]

The behavior during long press is

```
normal color -> very very light red -> very light red -> light red
```

**However, when it reach light red, it will just stop there. It can never reach pure red (#ff0000)**

What I'm expecting is

1. Retain the ripple effect.
2. Having color transition effect during long press, with the following

   normal color -> very very light red -> very light red -> light red -> pure red.

*My question is, why by using ripple, I can never achieve the color specific in `<ripple ... android:color="#ff0000">`. Even I long press on the item, I cannot end up at color `#ff0000`?*

Comment: That's because the `RippleDrawable` is built of two components: `RippleForeground` & `RippleBackground`. And both of these components are drawn with `alpha = 0.5f`.

Comment: If you look at line 847: [LINK](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.java#847), the code comment says: `Grab the color for the current state and cut the alpha channel in half so that the ripple and background together yield full alpha.`. This is not true - alpha blending is governed by: `finalAlpha = srcApha + dstAlpha(1 - srcAlpha)`. If you plug `0.5f` for `srcAlpha` & `dstAlpha`, `finalApha` will be `0.75f` - _not_ `1f` as the code comment suggests. Not sure what we can do about this.

Comment: @Vikram Thank u for pointing out the source. So, it seems that there is no way to achieve pure red, due to the alpha channel enforcement?

Comment: One approach I can think of is to have a `TransitionDrawable` as one of the layers in your `RippleDrawable` (_RippleDrawable_ extends `LayerDrawable`). This way, as the ripples are drawn, the `TransitionDrawable` goes from being transparent to full-blown `#ffff0000`. I haven't tried this, so the outcome may not be as I imagine :-p.